# Dojo - Leave/Dismiss FilteringSelect in DGrid on Enter

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid, dijit.form

I have a site with a table build with Dojo/DGrid.

Some columns of the grid use `editor: dijit/form/FilteringSelect` as editor, which works perfect. As the user hits the return key, the value is accepted and the editor closes.

Other columns of the same grid have a custom defined renderCell, because the unterdying store url differs in every row:

```
function myCustomRenderCell(object, item, node) {
    node.innerHTML = '<div class="myClass"></div>';
    var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
        label: 'myLabel',
        name: 'myName',
        displayedValue: item.myValue,
        store: new DstoreAdapter (
            new RestMemoryStore ({
                idProperty: 'id',
                target: 'myUrlToJsonData',
            })
        ),
        onChange: function(newValue) {
            var rowData = filteringSelect.store.get(newValue);
            var gridCell = this.domNode.offsetParent;
            var dataCell = grid.cell(gridCell);
            rowData.then(function(row){
                var eventObject = {
                    grid: this,
                    cell: dataCell,
                    oldValue: "",
                    value: row.name,
                    bubbles: true,
                    cancelable: true
                };
                on.emit(dataCell.element, 'dgrid-datachange', eventObject);
                grid.updateDirty(dataCell.row.id, 'myLabel', row.name);
            });
        }
    }, node.children[0]);
    filteringSelect._destroyOnRemove = true;
    filteringSelect.startup();
}
```

Unlike the default FilteringSelect mentions in the beginning this one is not left as the use hits the return key. The value is processed correctly. But except of pressing tab which places the cursor inside the next custom editor or using the mouse there is no way to leave this editor.

Any ideas how to set up this custom build FilteringSelect to dismiss on return like the default editor in the grid does?

Comment: see if you can remove focus on the custom one

Comment: thank you, this worked now.

Comment: sorry, roll back.
I tryed the code piece below. it worked as long as I clicked around in the debugger, but not without me clicking around.

Answer (score 0):

try out: add an event handler for key press:

```
onKeyPress: function(event){
    if (event.charOrCode == keys.ENTER) {
        filteringSelect.set("focused", false);
    }
}
```

Thanks to Manjunatha for the helpful hint.